# Turn by turn voice navigation in android using OSMBONUSPACK

Tags: map-directions

Hi I'm new to OSM is there any possible to develop/create turn by turn voice guidance in direction.Im using OSM MAPQUEST API.Also I have got route with ploy lines and route nodes also.?

Answer (score 0):

When you get the route, for each node there are instructions like "turn left 300m" etc. You can use Android text to speech for voice guidance.